# Aggregate all sources of parent pom in maven

Tags: java, maven

Part of the deliverables for the client include the source code of the project we are working on. I'm using maven with `mvn generate-sources`. The problem is that it includes all the dependencies and aggregates the sources per dependency. I'm trying to generate a flat structure with the `.java` files filtered on `groupid`.

The documentation is very evasive about [maven-source-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html). All the searches I do end-up pointing me toward filtering resources, which is not what I'am looking for.

The structure of my project is a parent pom with children and I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <resouces>
            <filter>
                    <include>com.mygroupid.project</include>
            </filter>
    </resouces>
</plugin>
```

What I am expecting:

- A 'fat' structure (all project sources aggregated by package name in one dir)
- No duplicate sources
- No code outside of my source group id

**Edit:**

Assuming a structure like this:

```
- module-1 pom.xml  // aggregate project
    |- module-1-core (has dependency to module-2 and module-2)
    |- module-1-war
- module-2 pom.xml  // aggregate project
    |- module-2-commons
- module-3 pom.xml  // aggregate project
    |- module-3-services
- // etc...
```

I would like the archive as follows:

```
- big-fat-code-sources.zip
    |- module-1-core sources + test source
    |- module-1-war sources + test source
    |- module-2-commons sources + test source
    |- module-3-services sources + test source
    |- // etc...
```

Comment: @khmarbaise: I tried the assembly plugin but we are facing an issue with it. It adds a /dependencies folder with the dependencies which adds a sub /dependencies folder (basically it traverses the dependency tree but does not check if the dependency is already added before adding the code) Because of that we have a huge archive with many times the same source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue with the `maven-assembly-plugin` and a lot of not obvious extra configuration.

In my `assembly.xml` descriptor I added a filter on the modules from the project:

```
<moduleSets> // 1
    <moduleSet>
        <includes>
            <include>mrkrabs-secret-recipe:*</include>
        </includes>
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
        <sources>
            <outputDirectoryMapping>${artifactId}-${version}</outputDirectoryMapping> // 2
            <includeModuleDirectory>true</includeModuleDirectory>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet> // 3
                    <directory>src</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/target/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/bin/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </sources>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

1. Includes all the modules in the maven project
2. Map each module to a directory with the artifact id and the version
3. Enforce filtering to keep sources only

This does not yet include the transitive dependencies and their source code.

So I added a filter on the dependencies:

```
<dependencySets> // 1
    <dependencySet>
        <includes> // 2
            <include>mrkrabs-secret-recipe:*</include>
        </includes>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <outputDirectory>/dependencies</outputDirectory> // 3
        <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering> // 4
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions> // 5
            <includes>
                <include>mrkrabs-*/**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.sql</exclude>
                <exclude>*.zip</exclude>
                <exclude>*.class</exclude>
                <exclude>*.jar</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        </unpackOptions>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

1. Includes all the dependencies of the maven project
2. Filter to include only the artifacts from the mrkrabs project
3. Put all the dependencies in a /dependencies folder
4. Force the filtering to be applied to the transitive dependencies
5. Apply extra filtering when unpacking the transitive dependencies:

   1. Include only mrkrabs projects (the `useTransitiveFiltering` should take care of this but does not)
   2. Exclude certain files we do not wanna see in the archive (.sql, .zip, .class, .jar)

Answer (score 2):

Using `source:aggregate` goal should solve this task:

```
mvn clean source:aggregate
```

Supposing you have the following project structure

```
- root pom.xml  // aggregate project
  |- module1 // jar module
  |- module2 // another jar...
```

With just following configuration in root pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
</plugin>
```

and the above command executed, it will produce a `.jar` in `target` folder, which will contain the all the *sources* of `modules` mixed together.

[More doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/aggregate-mojo.html) for this Maven goal.

Comment: i've updated my question as the structure is a little more complex than I firstly explained. Your answer works for a single aggregate project but does not add the other modules matching the same group-id located in different maven projects. Also the test classes do not seem to be added